# Сортировка и удаление из ArrayList

Tags: java, list, arraylist, java-stream, java-8

Всем привет!
Учусь Джаве, и решаю такую простую задачку:

**"Дается List положительных чисел и String, нужно вернуть List, из которого убраны все элементы String".**

Пытался решить через stream, но в нем я ещё очень слаб. Поэтому придумал вот такое вот:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Object> test = new ArrayList<>();
    test.add(1);
    test.add(2);
    test.add("a");
    test.add("h");
    test.add("s");
    test.add(4);
    test.add("r");
    test.add("q");

    System.out.println(filterList(test));
}
public static List filterList(final List list) {

    for (int i = 0; i<list.size();i++){
        if (list.get(i) instanceof String){
            list.remove(list.get(i));
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

}

По идее, должно работать, но оно не работает.

Удаляет элементы String через одного.

Вывод вот такой: *[1, 2, h, 4, q]*

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Почему не работает.

Если кто-то подскажет как написать это через стрим и разжует это, буду бескрайно благодарен :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static List filterList(final List list) {
    List<Object> result= new ArrayList<>(list.size());
    for (int i = 0; i<list.size();i++){
        if (!(list.get(i) instanceof String)){
            result.add(list.get(i));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Нельзя удалять из итерируемого массива. На место удалённого элемента сдвигается еще непроверенный элемент

Используя Stream

```
   test.stream().filter( f-> !(f  instanceof String)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!